# React material-ui-dropzone, How to get uploaded file full path

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropzonedialog

How can I get Uploaded File FullPath in React JS

[Uploaded File Schema in Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PPyV.png)

```
  <DropzoneDialog
          open={isFileUpload}
          onSave={handle_SubmitFiles}
          acceptedFiles={[".xlsx"]}
          showPreviews={true}
          showFileNames={true}
          maxFileSize={5000000}
          onClose={() => setIsFileUpload(false)}
          filesLimit={1}
        />

const handle_SubmitFiles = async (files) => {
    console.log(files);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "fullPath", the local path of the file in the user system? You can't

Comment: Yes, local path. Because of this, I need to load Excel to read each row from the sheet to import into a database table.

Comment: So you don't need the **path**, you need the file **content**. Right?

Comment: Yes. File Data.

Comment: I have used NPM readXlsxFile to fulfill requirements. Thanks @MoshFeu